# Function returning undefined? when its a string im trying to return

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Im connecting to a star wars api and trying to return a string with all the data, but its getting  returned as undefined, but when i console.log it, it works

```
https = require('https')
url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/'
getCharacters = () => {
    https.get(url, response => {
        let body = ''
        response.on('data', data => {
            json = data.toString()
            body += json
        })
        response.on('end', () => {
            data = JSON.parse(body)
            let nextLink = data.next
            return nextLink
        })
    })
}
console.log(getCharacters())
```

im expecting it to return a string with all the data but its getting returned as undefined

Comment: The HTTP call is **asynchronous**.  The callbacks are invoked when the network response is received, but the call to `https.get()` returns immediately.

Comment: @Paulpro I don't understand what u mean, i returned it with return nextLink, and when I call the function it doesn't return